Cdga morphism admits homotopy retraction iff it admits a retraction in homotopy category
I was reading the paper
"Rational approximations of sectional category and Poincaré duality", Proc. Am. Math. Soc. 144, No. 2, 909-915 (2016), MR3430865, Zbl 1337.55005, by José Carrasquel-Vera, Gabriel Thomas Kahl and Lucile Vandembroucq.
Here they define a homotopy retraction of a map $f \colon A \to B$ as a retraction of its relative Sullivan model.
But CDGA already admits a model structure and there is also a notion of homotopy. Two maps $f,g \colon A \to B$ are said to be homotopic if there is a map $H \colon A \to B \otimes \Lambda(t,dt)$ such that $H|_{t=0} = f$ and $H|_{t=1} = g$.
If we use this then retraction means there is a map $r \colon B \to A$ such that $rf \simeq id_A$.
In page 911 the authors said those two are equivalent definitions. Can you help me with this or suggest a reference? Thanks.
